# buildbot: run svn with --trust-server-cert

Tags: python, svn, project-management, build-process, buildbot

I am trying to install buildbot for my project.

I always run my svn commands with trust-server-cert option. How can I pass that to SVN thru buildbot?

I don't see there is a way for doing that. What is the shortest workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `extra_args` argument to the `buildbot.steps.source.SVN` [constructor](http://djmitche.github.com/buildbot/docs/0.7.11/#SVN).