# buildbot: run SVNPoller with --trust-server-cert

Tags: python, svn, project-management, build-process, buildbot

I asked [this similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908856/buildbot-run-svn-with-trust-server-cert) question and got a satisfactory answer. However, doing the same with SVNPoller doesn't work.

So how can I pass `--trust-server-cert` as an extra param to SVNPoller in buildbot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyPoller(SVNPoller):
    def __init__(...):
        SVNPoller.__init__(self, ...)

    def getProcessOutput(self, args):
        args += ["--trust-server-cert"]
        return SVNPoller.getProcessOutput(self, args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use extra_args
if specified, an array of strings that will be passed as extra arguments to the svn binary.